# Facebook PHP api. Searching people

Tags: search, facebook-fql

I trying to make a small app (with php and php facebook api). All what i need now working fine, but one thing not. I need to search a people and order it by mutual friend. I try do it with fql code:

```
$fql = "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE name=\"Lukáš Kotas\" ORDER BY mutual_friend_count DESC";
```

But I got this error

```
Exception: 604: Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql
```

//in fql faq is "name" marked as indexable...

Is another way how search people? Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the slashes.

```
$fql = "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE name="Lukáš Kotas" ORDER BY mutual_friend_count DESC";
```

Comment: The slashes are required by php syntax. But without in fql querty tool from facebook same error. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/ . Probably They disable a "name" indexing.

Answer (score 0):

`name` is supposed to be an indexable column, so you should be able to search on it, as you're attempting to do.

However, it is currently bugged.  This is a confirmed bug that Facebook is working to fix.  You can subscribe to the bug here:  http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/266794040030851